# SonarQube: (Catch a list of specific exception subtypes instead)

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a question about generic exceptions. How would we know which non-generic exception to use when you have a try that does multiple things.

For example:

```
  @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String policyInfo = (String) session.getAttribute("policyInfo");
            if(session.getAttribute("faxNumber") != null) {
                faxNumber = (String) session.getAttribute("faxNumber");
            }
            policyNumber = (String) session.getAttribute("policyNumber");
            JSONObject policyInfoObj = new JSONObject(policyInfo);
            JSONArray policiesArr = policyInfoObj.getJSONArray("policies");
            if (policiesArr.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject policyObj = policiesArr.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray insuredVehicle = policyObj.getJSONArray("insuredVehicle");
                checkInsuredVechile(insuredVehicle);
                termStartDate = policyObj.getString("effectiveDate");
                JSONArray addressArray = policyObj.getJSONArray("address");
                policySource = policyObj.getString("policySource");
                checkAddressArry(addressArray);

            }
            
             
             
            policyNumber = policyNumber.substring(0,5)+"-"+policyNumber.substring(5,7)+"-"+policyNumber.substring(7);
            
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        }catch(Exception  e) {
            logger.error("Exception in getting policy details",e);
        }
    }
```

So for `catch(Exception e) {` it will need a non-generic exception, but I am having trouble to determine what it can be.

Comment: Remove the catch, and see what your IDE complains is uncaught, then add them

Comment: @Michael remove the catch and leave the try? after I build it I get a Build Failure.

Comment: Either way. Just look at the error "X is uncaught" then add it. Rinse and repeat until it works

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/va/com/farmers/aem/farmers/core/models/GetPolicyDetails.java:[57,9] 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations`

Comment: ok thanks, it says that build failure do to ureported exception `unreported exception org.json.JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Comment: So add that one to a catch block, then rinse and repeat until it stops complaining

Comment: ok thanks, what if I remove the try-catch and the build is still successful, does that mean the try-catch was not needed? @Michael

Comment: The functionality is not identical. Look into the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You should catch only specific exeption like:

```
catch(org.json.JsonException e)
```

and not the base class `Exception`, which means all possible checked and unchecked Exceptions

Comment: how about RuntimeException ? can we use that for unchecked ?

Comment: The rule shoudl have in the documentaiton which structures are allowed. What is the rule id?